# remove header from phpbb3

Tags: php, header, phpbb, phpbb3

How can I delete this header from my phpbb3.
[image: phpbb3 header]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to edit the theme.
open styles/prosilver/template/overall_header.html

```
<div class="headerbar">
     <div class="inner"><span class="corners-top"><span></span></span>

     <div id="site-description">
        <a href="{U_INDEX}" title="{L_INDEX}" id="logo">{SITE_LOGO_IMG}</a>
        <h1>{SITENAME}</h1>
        <p>{SITE_DESCRIPTION}</p>
        <p style="display: none;"><a href="#start_here">{L_SKIP}</a></p>
     </div>

  <!-- IF S_DISPLAY_SEARCH and not S_IN_SEARCH -->
     <div id="search-box">
        <form action="{U_SEARCH}" method="post" id="search">
        <fieldset>
           <input name="keywords" id="keywords" type="text" maxlength="128" title="{L_SEARCH_KEYWORDS}" class="inputbox search" value="<!-- IF SEARCH_WORDS-->{SEARCH_WORDS}<!-- ELSE -->{L_SEARCH_MINI}<!-- ENDIF -->" onclick="if(this.value=='{LA_SEARCH_MINI}')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='{LA_SEARCH_MINI}';" /> 
           <input class="button2" value="{L_SEARCH}" type="submit" /><br />
           <a href="{U_SEARCH}" title="{L_SEARCH_ADV_EXPLAIN}">{L_SEARCH_ADV}</a> {S_SEARCH_HIDDEN_FIELDS}
        </fieldset>
        </form>
     </div>
  <!-- ENDIF -->

     <span class="corners-bottom"><span></span></span></div>
  </div>
```

delete it .

Answer (score 2):

with CSS for example:

```
#page_header{display:none}
```

Comment: Not really nice, but the easiest way^^ It's not a good idea to let the user download part's that are not needed, it's wasted bandwith